# Replace quotes of HTML tags attributes in a HTML string

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I want to replace every `"` for `'` in HTML tags for example, with javascript regex:

```
<div class="test1">Content 1</div> <div class="test2">"Content ""2</div>
```

for

```
<div class='test1'>Content 1</div> <div class='test2'>"Content ""2</div>
```

Using C# I would need to replace \" inside the tags for ', like;

```
<div class=\"test1\">Content 1</div> <div class=\"test2\">"Content ""2</div>
```

for

```
<div class='test1'>Content 1</div> <div class='test2'>"Content ""2</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: `<div class=\"test1\">` there is no attribute-value in this tag. There would be if the tag were `<div class="test1\">` In order to parse tag's attrib-values they must be valid, you can't just make stuff up.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe we can find a better solution than what you're asking for.

Comment: I would think of `<` character, followed by `not < or '` character one or more times, followed by `"`, etc. Its better if you try a regex and give us an actual problem

Comment: Also, it won't help you read `"Content ""2`, changing it because of this ="test2`">"`Content ""2

Comment: if you want to _view_ the content, strip all the tags `<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>` Replace with nothing.

Comment: Or a better one `"` character, that had before `<`, and is followed by `>`. @sln That is awful, much easier using positive look-behind and positive look-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C#
You may get some idea.

```
  (?<=\=)"|"(?=\>)

Match 1
1.  "
Match 2
1.  "
Match 3
1.  "
Match 4
1.  "
```

DEMO::  https://rubular.com/r/7NdNLySmZKlYnt

For Javascript:

DEMO: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3G2FGAV1SGF